# `self.send` on ReasonReact Compile-time Error

Tags: reason, reason-react

Given the following:

```
$cat src/Greeting.re
let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent("Greeting");

type action =
 | Click;

type state = {
    count: int
};

let make = (_children) => {
  ...component,
  initialState: () => {count: 0},
  reducer: (action, state) =>
    ReasonReact.Update({count: state.count + 1}),
  render: (self) => {
     let message = "Clicked " ++ string_of_int(self.state.count) ++ "x";
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={_event => self.send(Click)}
          />
          {ReasonReact.stringToElement(message)}
        </div>
  }
};
```

I get the following compile-time error:

```
  17 ┆ <div>
  18 ┆   <button
  19 ┆     onClick={_event => self.send(Click)}
  20 ┆   />
  21 ┆   {ReasonReact.stringToElement(message)}

  This record expression is expected to have type
    ReasonReact.componentSpec (state,  'a,  'b,  'c,  'd)
  The field send does not belong to type ReasonReact.self

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
>>>> Finish compiling(exit: 1)
```

I don't understand. Can someone please explain what the error is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to place your `let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent("Greeting");` line immediately before the `make` declaration, like so:

```
…
let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent("Greeting");

let make = (_children) => {
  ...component,
  initialState: () => {count: 0},
…
```

The reason for this is that the type of a reducer element is inferred based on other types (namely `state` and `action`) so it needs to be able to "see" them when it is declared.

Also, for the record, you should see a warning in the `bsb` output about this:

> Is this a ReasonReact reducerComponent or component with retained
>   props? If so, is the type for state, retained props or action declared
>   *after* the component declaration? Moving these types above the component declaration should resolve this!

Try to run `npm run start` again to see warnings!

Comment: After moving `action` and `state` declarations above `component`, which is now immediately before `make`, I'm seeing the same error. Any idea why that is, please?

Comment: I cannot replicate. https://gist.github.com/davidgomes/94b2561cbdb70ed5d09e974bc193b09d
Can you gist/github a full example for me to replicate? Your Greeting component works fine to me (clicking the button updates the state and the view).

Comment: I ran `npm install --save reason-react`, and then re-ran `npm install && npm start`. Then, it compiled and worked in the `webpack`-output `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I solved changing self.send with self.reduce, try to change:

```
 <button
        onClick={_event => self.send(Click)}
 />
```

in:

```
<button
  onClick=(self.reduce(_event => Click))
/>
```

I'm not sure but maybe self.reduce is old API, so probably we have old version of something

EDIT:
I just update reason-react to "0.3.1" and now work with send